# Run jQuery script on load and on resize for responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script for my dropdown menu. I would like the responsive (1024px) it turns off. And when I enlarge my window, he reactivates.

I managed to do more or less something that worked:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  if ($(this).width() > 1024 ){
    w.accessibleMenuConfig.init();
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, with this solution, when I load my page in desktop mode (> 1024px), I have to resize my window (one pixel is enough) to activate the script.

And if I shrink my window (I switch from desktop mode to mobile mode), the script is activated on mobile.

I tried this, but it does not work at all :

```
$(window).on('load resize', function (e) {
  if ($(window).width() > 1024 ){
    w.accessibleMenuConfig.init();
  }
})
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You can trigger a resize event on load. Just add `.trigger('resize')` to the end of your first snippet. Also note that you'll need to add a 'destroy' method for when the width drops below 1024

Comment: Or use the shortcut `.resize()` to trigger it

Comment: What specifically doesn't work with the second attempt? any errors thrown in your console?  Also, You have no code de-activating your init, so it will be activated if you start off on desktop and then resize to mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle both page load and resize events for this to work.
I would start with creating a function that does that logic:

```
function changeAccessibility() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1024 ){
    w.accessibleMenuConfig.init();
  }
}
```

Then, call the function on each of these events (window resize and window load - the latter happens only once).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  changeAccessibility();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
  changeAccessibility();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   enter code here
});
```

Check this: https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Code only answers may provide the answer to the problem, but an explanation helps a lot in understanding what you've changed and why it solves the problem.